# Button text only visible when hovered over with mouse

Tags: html, css, angular, bootstrap-5

The text on the button (Remove in this case) is only visible when hovered over with mouse. It's an angular project and it won't get overridden even if I try to give css for .btn as

```
background-color: blue;
```

| Button's text not visible | Button's text visible only when hovered over with mouse |
| --- | --- |
| [image] | [image] |

This is my html code for the button :

```
<button (click)="remove(item)" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm mt-2" style="color: white;">Remove</button>
```

This is the css for buttons in style.css :

```
 .btn-info{
    color:#fff;
    background-color:#0da8e4!important;
    border-color:#0da8e4!important
}

a.primary-btn{
    background:#05143f;
    padding:7px 20px;
    text-align:center;
    display:inline-block;
    color:#fff;
    border-radius:2px;
    font-size:14px;
    margin-top:5px
}
a.primary-btn:hover{
    background:#0da8e4;
    color:#fff
}

.active-link {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue when the button was inside a table. Bootstrap classes for the table were interfering with the button bootstrap classes.

Please put the button inside `<thead></thead>` or `<tbody></tbody>`

```
<table class="table table-hover" style="cursor:pointer">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th style="width: 20%;"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <button (click)="remove(item)" class="btn btn-primary">Remove</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have `btn-primary` on your html button tag as class, but in your css its `primary-btn`, so actually your css should do nothing to solve your problem.

As to why your text doesnt show, from what I can see, you have colored the text as white, while the button is also white, so the text should be showing, its more a problem of your background color.

Easiest solution would be :

```
<button (click)="remove(item)" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm mt-2" style="color: white; background-color: blue;">Remove</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. You have to wrap this button around additional div tag.

```
<div><button (click)="remove(tempCartItem)" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Remove</button></div>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).